# Maximum & minimum height of a binary tree

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree

According to my textbook when N nodes are stored in a binary tree H(max) = N
According to outside sources when N nodes are stored in a binary tree H(max) = N - 1

Similarly

According to my textbook when N nodes are stored in a binary tree H(min) = [log<sub>2</sub>N+1]
According to outside sources when N nodes are stored in a binary tree H(min) = [log<sub>2</sub>(N+1)-1]

Which one is right and which is wrong? Are they supposed to be used in different situations. In this case what would be the maximum height of a tree with 32 nodes?

I have been looking through my resources to understand this concept, and for some reason all my sources have different answers. I can calculate height when a binary tree is pictorially represented because that would involve number of nodes in each subtree. What about when only the number of nodes are given?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it has to do with the definition of height. If the height is defined by the number of nodes traversed from top to bottom then the max height is N. If it's defined as the number of hops between nodes, then it's N-1. Same goes for minimum height. That said, what counts is it's respectively O(N) and O(log N).